# Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I need get all the accounts of the @client (`has_many :accounts, as: :item` is the relationship). Have a Account model with :item polymorphic field (`belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true`, nothing more), Sale model  with `has_many :accounts` and `belongs_to :client`.

My query is:
`@accounts = Account.where(company: current_user.company_id).joins(:items).where({ items: { client_id: @client.id } })`

and receive the following error:
`Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :item`

```rb
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :category, required: false
  belongs_to :client, required: false
  has_many :accounts, as: :item
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :category, required: false
  has_many :sales
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I expect the output of Account object with all the @client payments.

Comment: I have a feeling that is not your query, since `Account` does not have an association of `:items`

Comment: I try with other queries, like inner/reference or implements the sales relationships, but doesn't works too. I don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively this can help you to get expcted results by breaking it in two query: -

```
sales_ids_for_client = @client.sales.pluck(:id)
accounts_of_given_client = Account.where("item_type = ? AND item_id IN (?)", 'Sale', sales_ids_for_client)
```

Comment: Yes i've done something like these a few minutes ago. Thanks so much!

Comment: Nice and simple, thank you.